# What is the function of the ~ operator?

Tags: c#, c++, c, operators

Unfortunately, search engines have failed me using this query.

For instance:

```
int foo = ~bar;
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm assuming based on your most active tags you're referring to C#, but it's the same `NOT` operator in C and C++ as well.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d2bd4x66%28VS.80%29.aspx):

> The ~ operator performs a bitwise
>   complement operation on its operand,
>   which has the effect of reversing each
>   bit. Bitwise complement operators are
>   predefined for  int,  uint,  long, and
>   ulong.

#### Example program:

```
static void Main() 
{
    int[] values = { 0, 0x111, 0xfffff, 0x8888, 0x22000022};
    foreach (int v in values)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("~0x{0:x8} = 0x{1:x8}", v, ~v);
    }
}
```

#### Output:

```
~0x00000000 = 0xffffffff
~0x00000111 = 0xfffffeee
~0x000fffff = 0xfff00000
~0x00008888 = 0xffff7777
~0x22000022 = 0xddffffdd
```

Answer (score 12):

In C and C++, it's a [bitwise NOT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#NOT).

Answer (score 3):

It's called [Tilde](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tilde) (for your future searches), and is usually user for bitwise NOT (i.e. the complement of each bit)

Answer (score 3):

[bitwise negation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#NOT), yields the bitwise complement of the operand.

> In many programming languages
>   (including those in the C family), the
>   bitwise NOT operator is "~" (tilde).
>   This operator must not be confused
>   with the "logical not" operator, "!"
>   (exclamation point), which in C++
>   treats the entire value as a single
>   Boolean—changing a true value to
>   false, and vice versa, and that C
>   makes a value of 0 to 1 and a value
>   other than 0 to 0. The "logical not"
>   is not a bitwise operation.

Answer (score 1):

It's called a tilde and it looks like some languages use it as a bitwise NOT: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tilde#Computer_languages

Answer (score 1):

Normally it's the [Negation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negation) operator. What is the Language?

Answer (score 0):

In C, it's the [bitwise complement operator](http://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/int/sx4ab.html).  Basically, it looks at the binary representation of a number and converts the ones into zeros and the zeros into ones.

Answer (score 0):

In most C-like languages, it is a bitwise not.  This will take the raw binary implementation of a number, and change all 1's to 0's and 0's to 1's.

For example:

```
ushort foo = 42;   // 0000 0000 0010 1010
ushort bar = ~foo; // 1111 1111 1101 0101
Console.WriteLine(bar); // 65493
```